# How change height for item in AppCompat ActionBar?

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar

I changed color for text and background by this code:

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:itemBackground">@color/itemBackground</item>
    <item name="android:itemTextAppearance">@style/TextAppearance</item>
</style>
<style name="TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/actionMenuTextColor</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
</style>
```

How can I change height for menu item like below?

[image]

Code for this menu:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<group android:id="@+id/group_hide_on_focus">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/test4"
        android:title="test4"
        app:showAsAction="never" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/test2"
        android:title="test2"
        app:showAsAction="never" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/test3"
        android:title="test3"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
</group>
```

Answer (score 0):

which menu height do you want to change ? can you be more specific ?

and have you considered using android:layout_height="xdp"

replace "x" with whatever height you want.... example : 50dp or so...

Comment: Item in menu in action bar like you can see on screenshot

Comment: never post a comment as an answer, wait until you earn some reputation.

Comment: sorry my mistake....use this:
<item name="android:height">20dp</item>

replace 20 with any number you want

Comment: Would you like to test your answer before post it? This isnt work too.